# How to set the banner logo length & height correct in Email Body

Tags: html, css

I have a Email Template designed using HTML, when i added a logo to the template it is not setting the logo static to the whole body of the email

```html
    <p><span style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18pt;"><span style="color: #396b53;"><img src="MyF_Banner.png" width="800" height="90"/></span></span></span></p>
```

Result:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZFJe.png)

Comment: First of all email template should be in table format. Please note

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use "Padding" style?. It will resolve the issue..

Go through this link as a reference .. https://emailmonks.com/blog/email-coding/step-step-guide-create-html-email/

Comment: Hi Sir,
Can you please let me know where to add Padding, I am new to HTML if you dont mind can you please help me with the syntax

Answer (score 0):

your image style should be 
style="width:100%;height:auto;"

Comment: Thank You Shirish, Width works but heigth is little bigger, is there any other option instead of auto

Comment: it would be easy if you shared a screen shot

Comment: the easy way to fix this problem now is resizing the height of your logo  or crop the height of the logo

Comment: Just added the logo output can you please the original thread